# Local/Production Crypt Returning Different Hashes

Tags: php

PHP `crypt` function is returning different hashes on local and production server.
On localhost the crypt hash validation is working fine, but on production its not.

```
Local: PHP 5.4.4
Procution: PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5
```

---

Code:

```
echo crypt('123123123');
```

Local Example Response:

```
$1$7ymnm8q/$M6HLj2JEvzWGElqlwjAKm0
```

Production Example Response:

```
$6$sbttg2v6$2YAU3dNKR/.MRGmbBV4sR8vEhr/L8aOMTej1u3gArhgIiCiJ5IFJ
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crypt is different on server than on local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058627/crypt-is-different-on-server-than-on-local-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing from the [PHP docu on `crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php):

> crypt() will return a hashed string using the standard Unix DES-based algorithm or alternative algorithms that may be available on the system.

So `cyrpt()`  is not bound to a specific algorithm, but uses, what the system supports.

You may use the following constants to see, which are supported in the system you are running `crypt()`:

- `CRYPT_STD_DES`
- `CRYPT_EXT_DES`
- `CRYPT_MD5`
- `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`
- `CRYPT_SHA256`
- `CRYPT_SHA512`

If you look at the examples in the docu, you'll see, that your local code uses MD5 for encryption, while the production server uses SHA-512.

Furthermore you don't specify a specific salt, so PHP will generate one for you, which will also differ in each invocation of `crypt()`.

Comment: When I try to validade the password, using: `(crypt($form->password, $user->password) != $user->password)` on the server it always return `false`. What should be the problem?

Comment: @LucianoNascimento `crypt()` is a one way function. So you can't decrypt that way. To compare two passwords, you would use something like `crypt( $db_pw, $salt ) == crypt( $entered_pw, $salt )`.

Answer (score 0):

The systems use different default hashing algorithms: `$1$` stands for MD5, `$6$` for SHA-512

You should specify the algorithm explicitly using the `salt` parameter:

```
crypt('123123123', '$6$somerandomstring');
```

See [`crypt()` documentation](http://php.net/crypt):

> **salt** An optional salt string to base the hashing on. If not provided, the behaviour is defined by the algorithm implementation and
>   can lead to unexpected results.